# Azure Data Factory Auto create table requesting table exists before copying

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to copy to Azure SQLDB.

This is a straight forward copy and I requested 'Auto create table'. My understanding is that ADF will automatically create the table if not is specified.

[image]

However, when I attempt to copy to Azure SQLDB I get the error "Table is required for Copy Activity"

I should mention the source is a sharepointpoint list, see image. However, I didn't see how that should be the problem.
[image]

[image]

Any thoughts on where I'm getting the error?

I am updating question with Dataset Database Properties
[image]

Comment: hey, can you send a screenshot of the database dataset properties?
You would need to explicitly add/provide a table name via edit

Comment: Hi @Nandan, I have just updated question with Dataset properties

Comment: please edit and provide a table name , Below link would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the Copy activity > Sink > Dataset > Table > Edit > type in the table name that should get created and run the pipeline.

Table that doesn't exist should get auto created

Similar thread :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/471851/data-factory-auto-create-table-in-copy-activity-do

Comment: Thanks for this ... You wouldn't believe I've done this a 1000 times before Doh!